# Merge Associations and replace absent value with 0

Tags: data, associations

I have two associations like this

```
In[211]:= assoc1 = 
AssociationThread[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]

Out[211]= <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6, g -> 7|>

In[212]:= assoc2 = 
AssociationThread[{a, b, c, d, f, g, h}, {12, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27}]

Out[212]= <|a -> 12, b -> 22, c -> 23, d -> 24, f -> 25, g -> 26, 
h -> 27|>
```

Now when i want to merge them by using `Identity`

```
In[213]:= Merge[{assoc1, assoc2}, Identity]

Out[213]= <|a -> {1, 12}, b -> {2, 22}, c -> {3, 23}, d -> {4, 24}, 
e -> {5}, f -> {6, 25}, g -> {7, 26}, h -> {27}|>
```

So here is the point: I want to obtain a value of "0" for the missing values of each association AND in the position according to the ordering of the associations (in this example for key `e` `{5,0}` and for key `h` `{0,27}` since `e` is missing in `assoc2` and `h` is missing in `assoc1`)

However I found a solution by first using a combination of `Complement`, `Union` and `Intersection` to obtain a sample of the unique keys within each association. Then I gave them a value of zero and merged them with each assoc by using `Total`. Finally I merged them again with `Identity` and obtained the desired result but that is far away from being an elegant solution....

Comment: if you can, you should accept @kglr's answer as the definitive answer. The trick I use with `Join` is  better accomplished with `KeyUnion`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`KeyUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyUnion.html) with `0&` as the second argument:

```
KeyUnion[{assoc1, assoc2}, 0 &]
```

> {<|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6, g -> 7, 
>     h -> 0|>,
>    <|a -> 12, b -> 22, c -> 23, d -> 24, e -> 0, f -> 25, 
>     g -> 26, h -> 27|>}

```
Merge[Identity]@KeyUnion[{assoc1, assoc2}, 0 &]
```

> <|a -> {1, 12}, b -> {2, 22}, c -> {3, 23}, d -> {4, 24}, e -> {5, 0},
>     f -> {6, 25}, g -> {7, 26}, h -> {0, 27}|>

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a list of all the keys you need, you can fill out your associations to have a default value by joining them with an association of only default values:

```
allKeys = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
default = AssociationThread[allKeys -> 0];
fillOut = Join[default, #] &;
Merge[fillOut /@ {assoc1, assoc2}, Identity]

(* <|a -> {1, 12}, b -> {2, 22}, c -> {3, 23}, d -> {4, 24}, 
 e -> {5, 0}, f -> {6, 25}, g -> {7, 26}, h -> {0, 27}|> *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution which uses `Lookup` to establish the default value 0:

```
Union @@ Keys[{assoc1, assoc2}] // 
 AssociationThread[#, Transpose@Lookup[{assoc1, assoc2}, #, 0]] &
```